# add click event for href located in the table row

Tags: jquery, html

I populate table with data from the `ajax` request like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/notes-rest/search',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#notes-table tbody').append(
                $.map(data, function(note, index) {
                    return '<tr>' +
                            '<td style="display:none;">' + note.noteId + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + $.format.date(new Date(note.date), "dd/MM/yyyy") + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + note.owner + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + note.name + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + note.text + '</td>' +
                            '<td><ul id="tags-list" class="hr">' + processTags(note.tags) + '</ul></td>' +
                            '<td><a href="#" id="delete-record">delete</a> | <a href="#" id="update-record">update</a></td>'
                            + '</tr>';
                }).join()
        );
    }
});
```

How to add `click` event for `href` (`delete-record` and `update-record`) in the last column? In that event I'd like to get the whole row with data, where the `href` is located. Table looks like this

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" style="table-layout: fixed" id="notes-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Owner</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Text</th>
        <th>Tags</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: id should be unique

Comment: Oh, my bad, I thought to generate dynamically during data appending

Comment: @user1432980  still you are facing problem? Or your question is resolved?

Comment: @AlivetoDie  well no, I resolved the problem. Though I used similar approach as @scaisEdge but without specifying id of `a`

Comment: @user1432980  so none of the answer worked for you? what about mine.using class instead of id and then use event delegation?did you tried that?

Comment: Well, @AlivetoDie I followed your suggestion not to use `id` but instead of event delegation I just made a fixed function for event

Comment: ok.glad that you found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to do like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/notes-rest/search',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#notes-table tbody').append(
                $.map(data, function(note, index) {
                    var rowIndex = index + 1;
                    return '<tr id="row-' + rowIndex + '">' +
                            '<td style="display:none;">' + note.noteId + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + $.format.date(new Date(note.date), "dd/MM/yyyy") + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + note.owner + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + note.name + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + note.text + '</td>' +
                            '<td><ul id="tags-list" class="hr">' + processTags(note.tags) + '</ul></td>' +
                            '<td><a href="#" onclick="deleteRecord(' + rowIndex + ');">delete</a></td>'
                            + '</tr>';
                }).join()
        );
    }
})
```

With function

```
function deleteRecord(id) {
    var recordId = $('#notes-table').find("tr")[id].cells[0].innerHTML;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/notes-rest/note/' + recordId,
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function() {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the onclick in the code

assuming you build a unique id

```
'<td><a href="#" id="delete-record-1" onclick="your_on_click_delete(id);">delete</a> | 
        <a href="#" id="update-record-1" onclick="your_on_click_update(id);">update</a></td>'
```

Comment: but will I be able to get the row data, where that `href` is located?

Comment: generate  an unique id for each row and pass the id to onclick function  in this way yuo ca easily inspect each row value

Comment: I can access inside `a`? because `this.id` I presume will return id of `a`

Comment: a as other tag is an html node and you can inspect as you prefer .. and once you a reference to you row .. you can do server (an client side) all you need